# For loop without the switch

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, switch-statement

I was wondering if there is a better way to write this for loop without the switch statement. Please ignore the append inside the for loops, that's just there for demo.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to concatenate variable names? For example instead of using var name and using a switch statement to assign value to the variable name, is there a way to do something like:

```
file + i // this will be the var file0, file1, file2.


var name = null,
    content = null;

var file0 = {
    name: null;
    },
// file2, file3, file4.
    file5 = {
    name: null;
    };


//  Something's length is < 10.
for(var i = 0, len = something.length; i < len; i++){
    switch(i){
        case 0:
            name = file0.name;
            break;
        case 1:
            name = file1.name;
            break;
        case 2:
            name = file2.name;
            break;
        case 3:
            name = file3.name;
            break;
        case 4:
            name = file4.name;
            break;
        case 5:
            name = file5.name;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    //  Better way to write name below?
    $("#someContainer").append('<li class="file" id="file' + i + '">' + name + '</li');
}
```

Comment: Use an array of files, instead of variables with numbers.

Comment: You can do this `var f = "file" + 0 + ".txt";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access variables by name:

```
var file4 = 42;
this["file"+4]++;
alert(file4) // 43
```

Not sure if it is more appropriate to use *this* or *window* to access global variables.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Could you explain what window[] does here? Thanks.

Comment: window is the object where variables go. Maybe *this* would be more appropriate, i will correct it.

Comment: It looks like using window will pollute the global scope and this can be messy when you are calling it within jquery or another function. Is there another way this can be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you're creating such a bunch of objects containing just one key-value-pairing each.
Why not using an array for your filenames?

```
var arrFileNames = ["file0Name","file1Name","file2Name"...];
for(...) {
    name = arrFileNames[i];
}
```

or, to shorten things (because there's no actual need for a name variable):

```
$("#someContainer").append('<li class="file" id="file' + i + '">' + arrFileNames[i] + '</li');
```